# org.json.simple JSONObject order in which items are inserted

Tags: java, json

I have an application which passes json data to a third-party application. The third party app requires that the fields in a JSONObject passed to it be in a certain order, or it returns an error "bad request".

My java code reads, in part:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public void postThirdParty (String name, String info, long offset, JSONArray address)
{
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject ();
    obj.put ("name", name);
    obj.put ("info", info);
    obj.put ("offset", offset);
    obj.put ("address", address);

    system.out.println (obj.toString ());
}
```

The output is:

{"name":"My Name","info":"My Info","address":[{"addressLine1":"My House No","addressLine2":"My Street","addressTown":"My Town","addressPostCode":"My Postcode"}],"offset":"My offset"}

Any idea why the fourth item to go into the JSONObject is being inserted ahead of the third?

Comment: JSON object fields are *unordered*, so says the JSON specification, so it someone wrote code requiring a JSON object with fields in a specific order, then they violate the specification.

Answer (score 0):

`JSONObject` does not preserve the order in which the elements were inserted. The underlying implementation of most `JSONObject`s is a `HashMap` (which does not preserve the order).

From the [docs](http://miamarti.github.io/HorusFramework/javadoc/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html):

> A JSON object. Key value pairs are unordered. JSONObject supports
> java.util.Map interface.

---

Not recommended, but if you are still looking for ordered keys in a `HashMap`, you can override the `.put(...)` and initialize the internal `Map` with a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap` which will preserve the order.